# Rubymotion Teacup variable scope

Tags: scope, rubymotion, teacup

Following the [Tweets example](https://github.com/rubymotion/teacup/blob/master/samples/osx/Tweets/app/main_window.rb) of Teacup, I'm trying to access a variable outside of the layout block

```
class WindowController < TeacupWindowController
    stylesheet :pref_window

layout do

  @loginButton = subview(
    NSButton, :loginButton,
    state: NSOffState,
    buttonType: NSSwitchButton, 
    action: 'login',
    target: self,
    )

  puts @loginButton.class

end

puts @loginButton.class
```

the first puts returns NSButton class, but the second one returns Nil class.

how can I access @loginButton if I need to programmatically make changes to it?

For example:

```
@loginButton.setState(NSOnState)
```

doesn't work outside the layout block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `attr_accessor` on the `WindowController`, then in the layout block you can use `self.loginButton` and it will be assigned on the `WindowController` giving you access to the button.

I'm also assuming the second `puts` is actually in another method and this is just example code.

```
class WindowController < TeacupWindowController
  stylesheet :pref_window
  attr_accessor :loginButton

  layout do

    self.loginButton = subview(
      NSButton, :loginButton,
      state: NSOffState,
      buttonType: NSSwitchButton, 
      action: 'login',
      target: self,
    )

    puts self.loginButton.class

  end

  puts self.loginButton.class
end
```

Comment: thanks for the hint. In the tweets example i linked in the question, they don't use self.

Comment: That's because they use the variable only inside the action: related to the variable.   So I can use the @loginButton variable inside my `def login` but not in other methods definition. Is this right?

Comment: I think I may have gotten this wrong... what your problem might be is simply that the layout block hasn't been called yet. Everything should be fine if you're using @loginButton in an action or something else that would be run after the view has been loaded and displayed.